# Leading and Trailing Spaces

Tags: ms-access, vba

I've come up with a bit of a weird situation. I have a string that was entered into a form from a webpage. I noticed that the string wasn't behaving as expected when I was trying to apply a filter.

The crux of the matter is depending on how I view the string it appears differently.

```
Form View - "523548"
Datasheet View - "  523548"
Raw Sql - " 523548"
```

Actually, when I view the datasheet value it appears as `"523548 "` but copies as `"    523548"`.

Asc(Left(string),1) tells me the first character is Chr9 (Tab Key)

I am really stuck to find out why this is happening or more importantly, what I can do to correct it.

Thanks!

Dave.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the tips. I found this function and added in a couple of items to suit my needs.

```
' Strip Illegal Characters
' http://www.utteraccess.com/wiki/index.php/Strip_Illegal_Characters
' Code courtesy of UtterAccess Wiki
' Licensed under Creative Commons License
' http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/
'
' You are free to use this code in any application,
' provided this notice is left unchanged.
'
' rev  date                          brief descripton
' 1.0  2010-10-23                    Writing files to disk that contain illegal file characters can cause sometimes obscure error message(s)
'
Public Function fStripIllegal(strCheck As String, Optional strReplaceWith As String = "") As String

On Error GoTo StripIllErr
'illegal file name characters included in default string are    ? [ ] / \ = + < > :; * " , '

Dim intI As Integer
Dim intPassedString As Integer
Dim intCheckString As Integer
Dim strChar As String
Dim strIllegalChars As String
Dim intReplaceLen As Integer

If IsNull(strCheck) Then Exit Function

strIllegalChars = "?[]/\=+<>:;,*" & Chr(34) & Chr(39) & Chr(32) & Chr(9)  'add/remove characters you need removed to this string

intPassedString = Len(strCheck)
intCheckString = Len(strIllegalChars)

intReplaceLen = Len(strReplaceWith)

If intReplaceLen > 0 Then   'a character has been entered to use as the replacement character

   If intReplaceLen = 1 Then   'check the character itself isn't an illegal character

       If InStr(strIllegalChars, strReplaceWith) > 0 Then
           MsgBox "You can't replace an illegal character with another illegal character", _
                  vbOKOnly + vbExclamation, "Invalid Character"
           fStripIllegal = strCheck
           Exit Function
       End If

   Else   'only one replacement character allowed

       MsgBox "Only one character is allowed as a replacement character", _
              vbOKOnly + vbExclamation, "Invalid Replacement String"
       fStripIllegal = strCheck
       Exit Function

   End If
End If

If intPassedString < intCheckString Then

   For intI = 1 To intCheckString
       strChar = Mid(strIllegalChars, intI, 1)
       If InStr(strCheck, strChar) > 0 Then
           strCheck = Replace(strCheck, strChar, strReplaceWith)
       End If
   Next intI

Else

   For intI = 1 To intPassedString
       strChar = Mid(strIllegalChars, intI, 1)
       If InStr(strCheck, strChar) > 0 Then
           strCheck = Replace(strCheck, strChar, strReplaceWith)
       End If
   Next intI

End If

fStripIllegal = Trim(strCheck)

StripIllErrExit:
Exit Function

StripIllErr:
MsgBox "The following error occured: " & err.Number & vbCrLf _
    & err.Description, vbOKOnly + vbExclamation, "Unexpected Error"

fStripIllegal = strCheck

Resume StripIllErrExit

End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, adjust your routine to not include the tab for new entries.

The old entries you can adjust with *Replace*:

```
NewValue = Replace([OldValue], Chr(9), "")
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd use the [Trim()](http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/trim.php) function here.  Although the link is for Excel, it's the same syntax in Access.

Use this function when you write the value to the table, and you can use this function to clean up your current data as well.  This should remove phantom tabs, as well as spaces.

Comment: The inbuilt VBA-`Trim()` only trims spaces, not TAB characters. You'd have to build your own function to also remove TABs.